# непонятное сжатие страниц

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Я создал сайт и указал всем блокам минимальное допустимое значение в min-width: 1300px; Проблема в том, что когда я открываю devtools и сжимаю сайт через браузер все хорошо сжимается, а когда сжимаю сам браузер появляется полоса прокрутки. Как это исправить? Пробовал открыть просто на экране меньше, все тоже самое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Она и в devTools у вас появляется на самом деле. Просто браузер иногда её не показывает, не знаю с чем это связано. Если вам не нужна прокрутка горизонтальная задайте в body{overflow-x:hidden;} и html(overflow-x:hidden;) - но учтите, что если сайт на Битриксе, нельзя в html задавать overflow. Такой вот Битрикс капризный)).

Comment: Очевидно же, раз минимальная ширина 1300px, то при достижении этого лимита появляется полоса прокрутки, т. к. больше сжиматься элементы не могут. Вы, конечно, можете использовать `overflow-x: hidden`, но я бы переосмыслил подобного рода дизайнерское решение целиком.

Answer (score -1):

min-width означает что блоки не могут быть уже этого значения, соответственно когда ты сжимаешь экран до меньших размеров появляется горизонтальный скролл, задай ширину 100% и пропиши padding какие тебе нужно (это и для адаптива в т.ч), или задай max-width 1300px (только для десктопа)

Comment: `min-width` как раз означает что блоки МОГУТ быть шире этого значения, но не могут быть 'УЖЕ.